# Getting accurate working area of monitor on display setting changes

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, user32

Working on an application that listens to changes to display setting changes (eg. monitor connections & disconnections). The problem that I'm running into is that a monitor's working area (the bounds of the monitor that excludes taskbars and other reserved display space) is not accurate when the event is fired.

Using either the `Screen` API or `GetMonitorInfo` from `user32.dll` return inaccurate bounds.

I'm guessing it takes a short while for the taskbar to reserve space when monitors are changed. If I set a small timer and then use the same methods, the bounds are accurate, but this feels like a very fragile solution.

To reproduce the issue:

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
    SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += new EventHandler(OnDisplaySettingsChanged);
    Application.Run();
  }

  private static void OnDisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
    {
      // `screen.WorkingArea` is not accurate here - does not include space reserved by taskbar.
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to reliably get a monitor's working area when display settings are changed? Alternatively, is there a way to listen to changes in a monitor's working area?

Comment: Microsot's own software is confused with it. Take for example windows 10 calculator app and move between vastly different monitors, plug and play such monitors and/or change settings. What you can achieve is extremely weird. Only way to overcome it in your own software is to wait a bit until the operating system figures it out for itself and then re-correct the layout of your widgets.

Comment: .NET itself uses this event to reset the Screens collection https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Screen.cs,118 have you tried to just run it in another thread (no timer) Task.Run(...) or post a message to some Window, to ensure your code always run *after* this event handling?

Comment: Unfortunately getting the same result when using `Screen.AllScreens` inside a `Task.Run` callback. I don't think the taskbar (or any another app bar) reserving desktop space causes `SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged` to re-emit. If there's a way to listen to when an app bar reserves spaces, it might be possible to combine both events and get an accurate working area...

Comment: The AppBar function API sends a undocumented message to the taskbar window when called. Hooking Explorer.exe is too ugly IMHO.

Comment: Were you able to figure this one out? I assume I can add a timer, but would be nice to avoid that.

Comment: @LOST if I remember correctly, it started working if I called the event handler whenever the location changed of any appbar windows (eg. the taskbar)